# Ubuntu 18.04 gnome-tweaks: how to add a script in Startup Applications?

Tags: scripts, gnome-tweak-tool

It seems that the "Startup Applications" menu in `gnome-tweaks` has been changed to be more *user friendly*. I used to be able to be able to add custom scripts there; now, instead I'm presented with a menu of desktop applications (e.g. Firefox, Terminal) which is useless to me, since the stuff I'm trying to automate is starting background scripts and not graphical applications. Is there a workaround (non-root) or a way to restore old behavior?

[image: new user-friendly un-useful startup applications UI]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should find another GUI application called "*Startup Applications*" installed. You can also launch it by running

```
gnome-session-properties
```

Use this instead to add your script to the list of start-up applications in an easy way.